# Merging 2 lists in C# with a combiner lamba

Tags: c#, linq, list, recursion

I need to merge two lists in a particular manner as the function describes below. This implementation uses recursion and works but seems kludgy. Does anyone know a better way to do this with LINQ, seems like there should be something like a `SelectMany` that can refer back to outer(unflattened) elements but I can't find anything

```
/// <summary>
/// Function merges two list by combining members in order with combiningFunction
/// For example   (1,1,1,1,1,1,1) with 
///               (2,2,2,2)       and a function that simply adds
/// will produce  (3,3,3,3,1,1,1)
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, 
                                          IEnumerable<T> second, 
                                          Func<T, T, T> combiningFunction)
{
    if (!first.Any())
        return second;

    if (!second.Any())
        return first;

    var result = new List<T> {combiningFunction(first.First(), second.First())};
    result.AddRange(MergeList<T>(first.Skip(1), second.Skip(1), combiningFunction));

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) is exactly what you want.

```
var resultList = Enumerable.Zip(first, second,
// or, used as an extension method:  first.Zip(second,
    (f, s) => new
              {
                  FirstItem = f,
                  SecondItem = s,
                  Sum = f + s
              });
```

**EDIT: It seems I didn't account for the "outer" style of zipping that continues even if one list completes. Here's a solution that accounts for that:**

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OuterZip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSecond> secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool firstHasCurrent = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
        bool secondHasCurrent = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();

        while (firstHasCurrent || secondHasCurrent)
        {
            TFirst firstValue = firstHasCurrent
                ? firstEnumerator.Current
                : default(TFirst);

            TSecond secondValue = secondHasCurrent
                ? secondEnumerator.Current
                : default(TSecond);

            yield return resultSelector(firstValue, secondValue);

            firstHasCurrent = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
            secondHasCurrent = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

*This function could easily be modified to pass boolean values to the result selector function to denote whether or not a first or a second element exist, if you need to check for that explicitly (instead of working with `default(TFirst)` or `default(TSecond)` in the lambda).*

Comment: nice, never noticed that one before. always thought it had something to do with compression :p   will it also support "outer merges" like dmitry was looking for?

Comment: It's all in what the result selector function returns; like in my example, you can return an anonymous type that contains references to the original items as well as the combined result (if you want to retain that information).

Comment: looks like zip exits after it hits the end of one of the enumerables, so if a second list is longer, it would omit those results.

Comment: Right you are. Let me come up with a solution that provides for the "outer" zip style.

Comment: thank you, I went down the yield path but could not get it to work appropriately, was really looking for a lazy eval version and this is it

Comment: I like the method name `OuterZip`.

Answer (score 1):

How about somethine like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMergeList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
                                  IEnumerable<T> second,
                                  Func<T, T, T> combiningFunction)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(first.Count(), second.Count())).
        Select(x => new
                        {
                            v1 = first.Count() > x ? first.ToList()[x] : default(T),
                            v2 = second.Count() > x ? second.ToList()[x] : default(T),
                        }).Select(x => combiningFunction(x.v1, x.v2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with just a good old fashioned loop. sure, it isnt as fancy, but its pretty straightforward and you dont have to use recursion.

```
var firstList = first.ToList();
var secondList = second.ToList();
var firstCount = first.Count();
var secondCount = second.Count();
var result = new List<T>();
for (int i = 0; i < firstCount || i < secondCount; i++)
{
    if (i >= firstCount)
        result.Add(secondList[i]);
    if (i >= secondCount)
        result.Add(firstList[i]);

    result.Add(combiningFunction(firstList[i], secondList[i]));
}
```